# How to keep focus on the URL bar when page is loaded

Tags: macos, safari

When I start loading a new webpage, if I focus the URL bar (e.g. CMD-L, select all the text in it), when the page loads it loses focus.

Slightly annoying when I'm typing in a new address to go to, then a slow-loading web page underneath kicks me out and I have to select it again.

Is there a way to stop that from happening?

Comment: The workaround here is to close the tab (command+w) and open a new tab (command+t) when you decide to open a new page, rather than focusing the address bar (command+L)